# Mysql sum reputation this month and select 2 other lower results before my result and 2 other higher results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate user's reputation for this month and then to find 4 nearest other results (2 are lower and 2 are higher) so at all to find 5 results at a sequence.
For example the reputation for certain user is 4500 so I should get at the end results: 2750, 3000, **4500**, 4650, 8900

This is the query I am having (it only selects for the certain user his reputation in the current month): `SELECT SUM(reputation_change) FROM activity WHERE user_id = '1' AND YEAR(datetime) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(datetime) = MONTH(CURDATE())`

My table is as following:
[image]

So the question is: how to make this to be performance-fair? Don't I have to restructuralize table and to add just for each user column `reputation_this_month`?

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a MySQL routine every night that creates a different table based off of the query above.  You'll see faster results when you SELECT from this table and you won't be taxing your production table with resource intensive queries